# How to retrieve id of a Image(saved in BLOB) from sqlite in swift

Tags: swift, sqlite

i have a table which have only two columns id and image [image: like this] now i want to retrieve id of the specific image if it exists from view controller i have wrote this code but didn't work[image: code] 
suggest me how can i fetch id of specific image

Comment: Please do not post code as a picture. Always post text as actual text. Pictures can't be searched or referenced. Please [edit] your question and replace the picture of code with your actual code, copied and pasted into the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can select both id and image as Select * from Images and then convert both fetch image and image view image in png . compare both images when ever they are equal select id [image: code]

Comment: Please do not post code as a picture. Always post text as actual text. Pictures can't be searched or referenced. Please [edit] your answer and replace the picture of code with your actual code, copied and pasted into the question. With just a picture, your answer isn't helpful to anyone performing a search.